# JPA Query with fetching/join retrieving only certain associations

Tags: java, jpa, fetch

once again my brain is less powerfull than the logic....

My Example has a one-to-many association where a Person has many Items.
An Item has a Date property. I want to do a query where the object tree of a Person with the determined associated set of Items is retrieved, i.e. 'query the Persons with Items having the Date greater than xyz'.

The last assert of each test method fails. But it expresses what I want to achieve.

Would be very nice to help me out here. Or is even my whole thinking wrong here?
I assumed that the goal is to retrieve the objects needed for the unit of work are fetched from the database. Not more or less. After work is done, the manipualted objects will be merged.

I uploaded the project [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/pAEDDto3/JpaSelectJoinDate.html).
It is Maven2. And can be run with: mvn test

Thank you for any help wringng out m brain :-)

Here's my Junit test:

```
package de.greyshine.jpaSelectJoinDate;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.*;

public class Tester {

    EntityManager em;

    static final Date DATE1 = createDate(2012, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
    static final Date DATE2 = createDate(2012, Calendar.MARCH, 1);

    static Date createDate(int inYear, int inMonth, int inDayOfMonth) {
        final Calendar theCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        theCalendar.set( Calendar.YEAR, inYear);
        theCalendar.set( Calendar.MONTH, inMonth);
        theCalendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, inDayOfMonth);
        return theCalendar.getTime();
    }

    @Before
    public void _junitBeforeClass() {
        final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "testPu" ); ;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.setFlushMode( FlushModeType.COMMIT );

        final Person p = new Person();
        final Item i1 = new Item();
        i1.date = DATE1;
        i1.person = p;
        final Item i2 = new Item();
        i2.date = DATE2;
        i2.person = p;
        p.items.add( i1 );
        p.items.add( i2 );

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist( i1 );
        em.persist( i2 );
        em.persist( p );
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testQueryTheItems() {

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final Query theQuery = em.createQuery( "FROM Tester$Item i WHERE i.date > :inDate" );

        theQuery.setParameter( "inDate" , DATE1, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<Item> theResults = (List<Item>)theQuery.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, theResults.size() );
        Item theItem = theResults.iterator().next();
        Assert.assertEquals( theItem.date.getTime(), DATE2.getTime() );
        Assert.assertNotNull( theItem.person );
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, theItem.person.items.size() );
    }

    @Test
    public void testQueryThePerson() {

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final Query theQuery = em.createQuery( "FROM Tester$Person p JOIN FETCH p.items i WHERE i.date > :inDate" );

        theQuery.setParameter( "inDate" , DATE1, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<Person> theResults = (List<Person>)theQuery.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, theResults.size() );
        Person thePerson = theResults.iterator().next();
        System.out.println( thePerson );
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, thePerson.items.size() );
    }

    @Entity
    @Table( name="persons" ) 
    public static class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public Long id;

        @OneToMany
        final Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(); 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [items="+ items +"]";
        }
    }

    @Entity
    @Table( name="items" ) 
    public static class Item {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public Long id;

        @Column
        @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
        Date date;

        @ManyToOne
        Person person;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [id="+id+"; date="+ date +"; person.id="+ (person==null?null:person.id) +"]";
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="applicationManagedPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>de.greyshine.jpaauction.entity.Buyer</class>
        <class>de.greyshine.jpaauction.entity.Seller</class>
        <class>de.greyshine.jpaauction.entity.Item</class>
        <class>de.greyshine.jpaauction.entity.Bid</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

@Amir Pashazadeh, 1st commenter:

Thanks for the fast reply, Amir. The testcase 'testQueryTheItems' does query the items. After having received the result list of Items I reference the many-to-one associated person. This person vice versa references all the associated items. I would like to have just the single item from the former query associated with the person.
Does it deal with transactional borders? The type of the persons Set is org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet. So is this still EAGER/LAZY fetching the referenced items?
If I now would end the transaction, would it be possible to have only one item associtaing one person, associating the one item?

Comment: Try querying the Items and then navigate to Persons, that will help you only having Items meeting your criteria to be in the query result

Answer (score 2):

ha,
Amir was the inspiring help. Yes it deals w/ TX borders. It did the follwoing changes to get it working:

```
public class Tester {

    static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "testPu" ); ;
    EntityManager em;

    ...     

    @BeforeClass
    public static void _junitBeforeClass() {
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.setFlushMode( FlushModeType.COMMIT );

        final Person p = new Person();
        final Item i1 = new Item();
        i1.date = DATE1;
        i1.person = p;
        final Item i2 = new Item();
        i2.date = DATE2;
        i2.person = p;
        p.items.add( i1 );
        p.items.add( i2 );

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist( i1 );
        em.persist( i2 );
        em.persist( p );
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void _junitBefore() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.setFlushMode( FlushModeType.COMMIT );
    }

    @After
    public void _junitAfter() {
        em.close();
    }
...
```

The EntityManager is in charge for my unit-of-work. When a unit-of-work starts the EntityManager is created by the EntityManagerFactory and closed afterwards! This is my real TX border and not the commit of the EntityManager's transaction.
...didn't I read that before... a million times... :-)
Well, the test 'testQueryThePerson' will pass. My guess was right.
On the other hand the test 'testQueryTheItems' will not pass at all but depeneds on the fetchtype of the Item's person association.
Setting it FetchType.EAGER will fetch the person and all the person's items.
Setting it FetchType.LAZY will fetch the person but no associated item of that person at all.
Nevertheless, this is not what I would immediately expect, because I will get the Item which declares an association and fetch type regarding the Person. The Person is fetched anyways no matter what fetchtype is set with the Item. But the fetchtype seems to influence one level more of associations...

Happy that I solved though another question mark rised bur I hope this will help someone out there on this planet...

Sorry for my english I ain't no native speaker...